# Install set of rpm's from an rpm which consists a script

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am creating an rpm which consists of a single script, which(script) installs a set of rpms. Rpm is created successfully and while installing, as a root user, got the below warning. If i try to execute the script manually, rpm's are installed successfully.

```
warning: waiting for transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock
```

Will it be possible to install rpm's from an rpm.

Env:
OS : RHEL-6.5
RPM version 4.8.0

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `rpm` from within an `rpm` transaction. You'll have to have the user download and run the script.

Comment: i am executing a script inside an rpm, which inturn executed rpm command instead straightaway. So is that applicable for the script executing an rpm command?

Comment: Yes, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron wrote you can't call an other rpm operation during package install (as the package db is locked).

For this purpose you can create either *metapackages* which are empty and just simply depending on other packages, or you can define *group packages* to install a set of packages. 
 In order to create a metapackage, just create a .spec file which doesn't install anything, but in its `Requires:` field lists the packages you actually want to get installed. If needed, in a `%pre` or `%post` script you can print a message to the user to explain what is happening.